# How fast is allocation and deallocation in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, performance, loops, timer, allocation

I know this probably depends on how large of an object you are allocating, but I just want to know if I keep on doing things this way I will run into problems later on. For right now, everything seems fine. I am using Cocos2D.

Take this method for instance:

```
-(void) checkCGPointDistances{

    CCSprite *tempSp;

    CCLabelTTF *tempLabel;

    for(int i=0; i<hummingBirdsMax; ++i){

        tempSp = [hummingBirds objectAtIndex:i];

        checkDistance = [[CheckDistance alloc] init];

        if([checkDistance checkDistanceWithLimit:tempSp.position withPoint2:hero.heroSprite.position withLimit:150] == YES){

            if(hero.heroSprite.position.x > tempSp.position.x){
                tempSp.flipX = YES;
            }else{
                tempSp.flipX = NO;
            }

            tempLabel = [hummingLabels.labelsArr objectAtIndex:i];


            [tempLabel setString:@"Hello!"];

            [hummingLabels.deactivateLabelToggle replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        }

        [checkDistance release];

    }

    if(abilityRushH == 0){
        checkDistance = [[CheckDistance alloc] init];

        if([checkDistance checkDistanceWithLimit:rushH.rushHSprite.position withPoint2:hero.heroSprite.position withLimit:32] == YES){
            [rushH.rushHSprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];

            abilityRushH = 1;
            NSLog(@"horizontal rush activated");
        }

        [checkDistance release];
    }

    if(abilityRushV == 0){
        checkDistance = [[CheckDistance alloc] init];

        if([checkDistance checkDistanceWithLimit:rushV.rushVSprite.position withPoint2:hero.heroSprite.position withLimit:32] == YES){
            [rushV.rushVSprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];

            abilityRushV = 1;
            NSLog(@"vertical rush activated");
        }

        [checkDistance release];
    }
}
```

Notice how I'm allocating and deallocating checkDistance for every loop in the for loop? This method is also being called on a timer very quickly.  The reason I decided to do the allocation over and over inside the loop verses outside is because the number of hummingBirdsMax may be 0, so it would not need to do allocation at all.  I suppose I could just check if hummingBirdsMax > 0, but is the way I'm doing it make much difference?

The class that it allocates just checks a distance between to CGPoints and returns a bool.

Comment: Could you post your implementation of `CheckDistance`? Especially its `init` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing. There's no way to tell whether object allocation and deallocation are performance bottlenecks in your code without some work in the profiler (Shark or Instruments). As with all performance optimization decisions, there's no reason to even speculate without some data.

That said, if all the `CheckDistance` class does is perform a calculation, it's not really an object (i.e. that encapsulates state and exposes behavior). Why not just implement the calculation as a C function? Unlike the managed Java/C# world that many folks are now used to, not everything has to be (nor should it be) a class.

Comment: Thanks Barry. If it's a normal C function that's outside the class, doesn't it need to be in a separate class?  Some methods that I put inside different classes are large enough to make sense to do so, or else I just have way too much code in one class.

Comment: @VagueExplanation, the code doesn't have to be in *any* class. You'll have to declare the function in a header file so that it can be called by other code, but you can put the definition in any `.m` file. Note that virtually all of the CoreFoundation (and many other OS X/iOS) APIs are C functions...

Comment: Thanks Barry this is amazing, but how would I call a method if the definition is in another .m file? Right now I do something like hero.vel = [velocity getVel:hero.heroSprite.position withEndPoint:heroControl.moveEndLoc withSpeed:hero.speed];

Comment: Never mind I got it. Using method definition with + instead of -

Comment: + makes it a class method not a function, you are still going to have a little performance loss while that gets pushed through the objective c runtime.